# WiFi shown as connected but no net access after boot

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, internet-connection

My windows 7 desktop computer is behaving very strange when I reboot it or when it resumes from hibernation. The network connection manager lists my computer as connected and shows the correct IP address, but whenever I try to connect to anything it fails with timeouts. This lasts for approximately 2-5 minutes after which everything is working exactly like they should. During the downtime, all connections fail, even connections to the local net (pinging the router for example).

The WiFi dongle in question is an Asus N13 USB dongle which works flawlessly in Linux (although I did have some trouble with the drivers in Ubuntu 11.10). When I take a look at the traffic in wireshark during the downtime, it shows lots of ARP packets where both the router and the WiFi dongle are asking the net who has their respective IPs.

The router in question is a Netgear N300 running DD-WRT. Does anyone have any idea what is happening?

Comment: What do you have as an antivirus? I have had problems with programs like McAfee that affect internet connections

Comment: Avast! Antivirus. I don't think it affects my internet connection, but I will try disabling it and see what happens.

Comment: I just had a case the other day very similar to yours where the internet was saying connected but it wouldnt load webpages. I uninstalled Mcafee and it worked. It had to do with Mcafees firewall. Not saying that is your problem but its possible... Another thing that seems to make this a possibility is that it works with linux.

Comment: Will definitely try. Antivirus programs have given me weird problems before, so it might be a possible cause.